# Using Numpy arrays for looping

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scikit-image

How would one go about converting `p = img.ptr<uchar>(row);` which is written using OpenCV in C++, into OpenCV's Python bindings?

From what I understand, since images are represented as NumPy arrays in OpenCV Python - does this mean that it could be represented as `p = img[row, 0, :]` or perhaps `p = img[row, 0]` for a grayscale image?

This construction of `p` is in a for loop, and it is in order to facilitate looping through every pixel row by row.

I tried a simple for loop to loop through every pixel in the image, but I also need to implement functionality such as blanking out a given row after looping through it.

If I can understand what `p` would translate into in Python, I am confident it can be done easily. I looked at solutions that involved linking Python code with C++ files, but I am a beginner and want to keep things simple.

I was also considering using SKImage, would anyone recommend that library?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full loop? Converting this statement by statement isn't really useful. Also iterating pixel by pixel in Python is gonna be horribly horribly slow. What's the goal here?

Comment: @DanMašek - I want to build a simple application that recognises all the highlighted text in my textbooks. That's why I'm iterating row by row. I am trying to adapt some code I found in a GitHub repo to suit my needs. Do you perhaps know of a faster way I could do this, using Python?

Comment: @DanMašek and you are right about it being really really slow :). I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's the interpreter overhead, among other things. The key is making the most out of the optimized functions provided by numpy and OpenCV (e.g. one call that performs some operation on entire array, taking advantage of SIMD and sometimes multitheading). If you need more, perhaps something like Cython might help. | Make a [mcve] and show the original c++ code, and then we can talk about some concrete ways on how it could be improved.